# Dimple JS unable to sort series data

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I can't get the chart categories to match the legend. Maybe my data could be laid out better? Items should sort based on Date inside of each category.

Please see Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gcu2Y/

Using the addOrderRule doesn't seem to be working.

```
s1.addOrderRule(["January 2012", "January 2013"]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you want to sort them by date? or  by what?

Comment: I'd like to have the blue column (January 2013) be the first item in the group, so it matches the legend sorting.  The columns are sorted 2013 then 2012 now. I'd like to reverse that.  So overall it should be Category on the y Axis and Percentage and Count sorted by date inside of each xAxis group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the category axis which needs ordering not the series. So you just need to add:

```
x.addGroupOrderRule(["January 2012", "January 2013"]);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcu2Y/1/

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a million John!

Comment: Changing one of the values to 0 breaks the addGroupOrderRule you suggested previously to fix the legend sorting.  Setting that value to 0.000000001 sorts legend correctly. Check out the modification: http://jsfiddle.net/U3sVW/1/ Wondering if it is a bug in Dimple